# Help optimizing slow WP_Query with meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm trying to create a custom `WP_Query`. Right now, I have two meta fields, `roi_min` and `roi_max`. The ideia is to get posts that has a `roi_min` greater than the selected value, and a `roi_max` lower than the selected value. So far so good. The problem comes by when you add different cases.

The query needs to take into account all posts that doesn't have `roi_min`, OR `roi_max` set, OR have both set as an empty string (`''`), OR have only `roi_min` set, and `roi_max` as an empty string. There's a lot of OR cases.

Right now, my query is like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'tax_query'      => Custom_Class::build_tax_query(),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     =>  array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_min',
                'value'     => $roi_min,
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_max',
                'value'     => $roi_max,
                'compare'   => '<=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_min',
                'value'     => $roi_min,
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_max',
                'value'     => '',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_min',
                'value'     => '',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_max',
                'value'     => '',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_min',
                'value'     => '',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'roi_max',
                'value'     => '',
            )
        )
    ),

);
```

The query seems to work, but it's really slow, and sometimes it doesn't load at all. My guess is that is because the `OR` relation.

Any tips on how to optimize this? The less meta_query we can use, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the better solution would be to, when updating your `post_meta` to set a value, such as 0 or -1 for the min and something stupid high like 9999999999 for the max, versus deleting the post meta. This will solve your issues and make your query bearable.

Comment: Use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/timer_stop to check your query time, then compare  `get_posts` vs. `WP_Query`. I saved a ridiculous amount of time off some queries.

Comment: @jgraup `get_posts()` is only a little bit faster because it passes `'no_found_rows' => true` to `WP_Query` which legally breaks and skips pagination. If you pass `'no_found_rows' => true` to `WP_Query`, you will get the same effect. As this is a paginated query, you would really want to avoid `get_posts`

Comment: Meta queries creates complex SQL queries which involves `INNER JOIN` etc. The more nested the `meta_query` becomes the more involved the SQL query becomes. In general, any `OR` condition is quite expensive. If you have a large database, such queries can kill a page as it runs into maximum execution time being reached. There is not really much you can do about this, except what @Howdy_McGee proposed. You might want to look into transients as well to store such heavy queries